# Returning char pointer from C function

Tags: c, pointers, char

I need help to check if my code is correct. The code is too big to include entirely, so I will paste only the affected parts.

```
char *tmp;
tmp=Decode_URL(tmp_data);
sprintf(Data,"%s",tmp);
tmp=Decode_URL(tmp_backup1);
sprintf(DataB[0],"%s",tmp);
tmp=Decode_URL(tmp_backup2);
sprintf(DataB[1],"%s",tmp);
tmp=Decode_URL(tmp_backup3);
sprintf(DataB[2],"%s",tmp);
tmp=Decode_URL(tmp_backup4);
sprintf(DataB[3],"%s",tmp);
tmp=Decode_URL(tmp_backup5);
sprintf(DataB[4],"%s",tmp);
```

The `Decode_URL` function returns a `char *`.

So my question is, is it correct to always use `tmp` to receive the `char *` returned by the function? Or I should create more `char *tmpx`, one for each call to `Decode_URL`?

---

EDIT FOR MORE INFO:

```
char *Decode_URL(char *url){
      char *check;
      check=EnDeCrypt(some vars here);
      return check;
}

char *EnDeCrypt(const char *pszText, int iTextLen, const char *pszKey)
{
    char *cipher;
    int a, b, i=0, j=0, k;
    int ilen;
    int sbox[256];
    int key[256];

    ilen = strlen(pszKey);

    for (a=0; a < 256; a++)
    {
        key[a] = pszKey[a % ilen];
        sbox[a] = a;
    }

    for (a=0, b=0; a < 256; a++)
    {
        b = (b + sbox[a] + key[a]) % 256;
        swapints(sbox, a, b);
    }

    cipher = (char *)malloc(iTextLen);

    for (a=0; a < iTextLen; a++)
    {
        i = (i + 1) % 256;
        j = (j + sbox[i]) % 256;
        swapints(sbox, i, j);
        k = sbox[(sbox[i] + sbox[j]) % 256];
        cipher[a] = pszText[a] ^ k;
    }
    return cipher;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: its ok with one tmp!!! till the previous one is not used again.

Comment: depends on how that *char is created, stack wise, heap or returning const.

Comment: its probably ok until and unless the returned value is not the address of a local variable of the `Decode_url()`

Comment: It depend on what you return from `Decode_URL`. If you return a pointer to a local variable (like an array inside the function) then you suddenly have what is known as _undefined behavior_.

Comment: That will _almost_ work. I say _almost_ because you don't terminate the string you return, you don't even allocate memory for the string terminator. You also have a memory leak, you allocate memory for the returned string but you never free it.

Answer (score 5):

This of course depends on where the memory comes from, that `Decode_URL()` is returning a pointer to.

If it's a static array, your usage is fine.

If it's dynamically allocated (by `malloc()` or any of its friends), then you're leaking memory.

Comment: That usage is undefined behaviour for a static array defined in the scope of `Decode_URL`.

Comment: +1 for mentioning memory leak. also adding about returning local array address will complete the answer.

Comment: @Paulpro how so? standard guarentees storage durationof static objects to be the same as the lifetime of execution of program?

Comment: @Koushik Teh standard guarantees static memory as long as that part of the stack is still in use. Once `Decode_URL` returns, it is not.

Answer (score 2):

It is correct. you could also go with

```
sprintf(DataB[4],"%s",Decode_URL(tmp_backup5))
```

Answer (score 0):

As long as you don't need to do anything more with the data, sure, why not?

Answer (score 0):

What we need to really know is what Decode_URL does to create the memory that the returned char pointer points to, is it malloc in which case you will need to release it, is it static in which case you need to be careful how you use the function and the data returned as the function will then not be reentrant nor thread-safe.

Answer (score 0):

It is correct since no other usage is being made with tmp, though you might want to consider

a macro for this:

```
#define SET_TEMP(BACKUP, TMP, DATA) \
        TMP=Decode_URL(BACKUP);     \
        sprintf(DATA,"%s",TMP)
```

and use it like this:

```
SET_TEMP(tmp_backup1, tmp, DataB[0]);
...
```

anyway, you are good to go, macros is just a better style of coding.

## EDIT:

after seeing your added code, you do have a memory problem.

this is how your macro should look like:

```
#define SET_TEMP(BACKUP, TMP, DATA) \
        TMP=Decode_URL(BACKUP);     \
        sprintf(DATA,"%s",TMP);     \
        free(TMP)
```

and use it like this:

```
SET_TEMP(tmp_backup1, tmp, DataB[0]);
...
```